# auto adjust size of a image for small monitors

Tags: html, css

I have placed a logo on my web site.
Logo size is 110px x 109px
Now I want to do something for automatically make smaller the image size when someone tries to view my web site with a small monitor.

Comment: Please post code you have tried.

Comment: No Bro.
That article isn't match for me.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest is to only specify `width`. If you don't specify a height and only a width the proportions stay the same.

Now you have to give it a percentage based width so that it scales with it's parent.

[JSFiddle demo: Percentage based scaling example](http://jsfiddle.net/NmBLu/)

**NOTE:**
The parents' size must change when you make the screen size smaller.

This could be done by:

- Percentage based scaling (showed in the demo)
- CSS3 Media Queries (You change the parent's width whenever the screen size increases/decreases.

[JSFiddle demo: CSS3 Media Queries example](http://jsfiddle.net/NmBLu/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
<div class="logo">
    <img src="logo.png" alt="Logo" />
</div>
```

And the CSS,

```
.logo img {
    width: 110px;
    height: auto;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {

    .logo img {
        max-width: 60px;
        height: auto;
    }

}
```

See responsive style-sheets
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/

Answer (score 0):

just try this.

using jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).resize(function(){

   $('body').css({'min-height':$(window).height()});
   });
   $('body').css({'min-height':$(window).height()});
})
```